# Geotechnical Profile using jupyter platform

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

In the following code I have used matplotlib's line command to visualize soil layers. How can I add another SPT profile along the same Z values but with different magnitude of value (say 0 to 60)? It may use a different scale but, must be visualized beside the original Z value to show soil profile alongwith SPT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Sample data (replace with your actual data)
points = [
(1, 2, [3, 4, 5], ['sand', 'clay']),
(2, 3, [4, 5, 6], ['clay', 'sand']),
(3, 4, [5, 6, 7], ['sand', 'sand'])
]

# Initialize 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define color dictionary for different types
color_dict = {'sand': 'orange', 'clay': 'brown'}

# Plot points and lines connecting z values of each point
for x, y, z_values, line_properties in points:
for i in range(len(z_values)-1):
    ax.scatter([x]*2, [y]*2, z_values[i:i+2], color=color_dict[line_properties[i]])
    ax.plot([x]*2, [y]*2, z_values[i:i+2], color=color_dict[line_properties[i]])

# Set labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('3D Plot with Lines Connecting Z Values of Each Point (Color Coded by Line     Property)')

# Legend
for soil_type, color in color_dict.items():
ax.scatter([], [], [], color=color, label=soil_type)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

`

I am expecting a revised code with options of adding the SPT values for each borehole alongwith soil layers